# QTableWidget how to have a cell selected for editing from code and/or with single click

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, editing, qtablewidget

Two part question:
I have a 10x10 QTableWidget with QTableWidgetItem in each cell.
For some reason, clicking on a cell is not sufficient to edit it, I need to double-click the cell to enter it.

1. Is there a way to change this behavior to single click
2. Is there a way to have 2nd cell in 1st row selected and ready for editing by default when window is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the editing behaviour in various ways with [setEditTriggers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop).

For single-click, try:

```
table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.CurrentChanged)
```

The current edited cell can be set with [editItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#editItem):

```
table.editItem(table.item(0, 1))
```

To select a cell without editing it, use [setCurrentCell](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setCurrentCell):

```
table.setCurrentCell(0, 1)
```

Comment: It worked, Thankx! I found that `self.table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers)` works best.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use setCurrentCell.

table.setCurrentCell(0,1)

QTableWidget.setCurrentCell (self, int row, int column)